# Small hole in shower base

Tags: shower, leak, silicone

I have a shower at home that was installed before I arrived.

Water leaks when someone takes a shower. By having water running through the drain, I confirmed the leak does not come from the drain or the tap. The leak therefore simply comes from water splashing inside the shower, and getting outside.

The leak appears at the back of the shower, but I suspect it might come from the water getting out of these 2 holes.

I see 2 small holes inside the base of the shower, that are without caulk.

My first idea is to put a lot of caulk in these holes, to make it watertight.

Before I do so, I wanted to confirm with more knowledgeable people than me if that was a good idea? I am guessing these holes are meant to have screws in them? Unless they are a sort of water safety level, and are supposed to stay empty, to prevent water from overflowing?

[image: shower]
[image: two small holes]

Comment: I suggest you let everything dry completely, then use a small stream of water to investigate. My guess is that those holes are not really a problem and that there's a seal that's failed or not installed correctly along the bottom of the glass frame. These showers must be sealed correctly (and _not_ sealed in certain places) for water to drain properly. Also, whoever made that colossal caulk mess should be banned from caulking for life.

Comment: Common things are common.  Heavy leak might reflect trouble where water flow is heaviest which is the main drain.  Before you go a-caulking, try running water thru a hose down to go out the drain without wetting the sides at all.  The fact that it comes out at the back might have to do with how water trying to drain out and missing tracks along before it comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My parents have one of those kinds of showers (corner mounted)  You will always have leaks with it setup that way.  If you want to make it so the shower won't leak then you will get rid of the water pik and replace it with some chrome tubes and bracketing then mount a shower head so that it is pointing straight down so that it is not possible to angle the head so that it sprays directly on the sides.  The sides should only have water going on them that is indirectly bouncing off the person taking a shower.  A direct spray puts too much volume on the sides and will force the water down and under the sides and then back up.

You can try attacking everything with silicone but it's just going to be a bandaid.

There's a reason why those corner showers aren't that popular.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. We don’t use the water piks, only the shower head that points down directly. In spite of that, the leak is still quite heavy...